# How to encode Turkish characters in base64 data in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, unicode

I'm using [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) package to save text-based files in **.eml** format. However, Turkish characters such (ı, ş, ç) aren't encoded properly.

Example:

```
Mailin i=C3=A7erisinde herhangi bir dosya numaras=C4=B1 tespit 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Its saved in base64 data format. How do I encode these characters correctly?

Comment: How do you encode it?  Show us your code.

Comment: Base64 can encode *anything*. It is nothing more than an alternative to binary storage. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: What you show here is the [quoted-printable](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1521.html) ("quopri") encoding of the UTF-8 encoding of the text. If you encode this with base64, you have three layers of encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package to solve utf-8 problem.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-base64

`https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-base64`

node.js

`var Base64 = require('js-base64').Base64;`

es6+

`import { Base64 } from 'js-base64';`

then just encode and decode the string

```
Base64.encode('şçiadşaqüğkmkanİæa');   
Base64.encodeURI('şçiadşaqüğkmkanİæa');  

Base64.decode('ZGFua29nYWk=');
```